# Grub can't find Windows 10 boot entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Was dual booting Win10 with Mint Linux, recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and since than i can't see Win10 boot entry in grub, just the standard "ubuntu", "advanced options" etc. I surely ran "update-grub" a couple of times. Both OSs r on the same HDD and i can see the windows partition within the file manager. Help!

Comment: This is an Ubuntu or official flavor of Ubuntu question & answer site.  Other distributions are off-topic as we have no idea what changes they made. But this may apply as Windows turns fast start up back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If it does not solve your problem automatically, please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair. @oldfred _“recently installed Ubuntu 18.04“_ I find this on-topic. However, not voting to reopen now until details from Boot-Info are provided.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you installed Ubuntu in a different boot mode. Did you see install alongside windows option when you installed? I think not. So what you have to do is uninstall Ubuntu and install Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows. For now, you should be able to access ubuntu by enabling Legacy BIOS compatibility mode in firmware settings.